# Difference between `.append` and `+=` when used inside functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to understand how the `callback` function in `Pool.apply_async` works, and ran into the following issue.  Outside of the callback, I define

```
results = []
```

and want to use the callback to append return values from the worker process to `results` as the values become available.

The strange thing, though, is that this statement (in the callback) works :

```
results.append(t)
```

but

```
results += [t]
```

reports an unassigned reference error.

What is going on?  Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the complete code :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random

results = []

def f(t):
    return t

def cb_append_result(t):
    # reports "local variable 'results' referenced before assignment"
    # results += [t]    

    # Okay
    results.append(t)   # works

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool() 
    t = random.random()

    pool.apply_async(f,args=(t,),callback=cb_append_result)    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("Result is {}".format(results))
```

(ADDED) The issue has nothing to do with multiprocessing or callbacks (see answer below).  But to fix the problem above, the callback function should be written as

```
def cb_append_result(t):
    global results
    results += [t]
```

Comment: Yep - that is it!   I in fact suspected something like this, but couldn't get past the fact that both `append` and `+=` logically do the same thing (change an existing object).   I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in fact has nothing to do with multiprocessing or callbacks.    The key is to use the `global` statement to explicitly reference a global variable.

Here is a simple code demonstrating the issue.

```
y = []

# doesn't work
def f(x):
    y += [x]

# works
def g(x):
    global y           # <===== Answer!!
    y += [x]

# works
def h(x):
    y.append(x)

# f(1)   # local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

g(1)     # works
print(y)

h(2)     # works
print(y)
```

with the output :

```
[1]
[1, 2]
```

So in fact, the `callback` business, etc was all obfuscation.  I've edited my original post.